# Install Tensorflow Object Detection API - 'cp' error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I'm trying to install the Tensorflow Object Detection API, following several tutorials and the official documentation ([Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)). I've encountered multiple times the same error when running through the command prompt the following command:

```
>cp object detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've also tried using "copy" instead of "cp" but no result.

P.S. I've installed GPU support as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cp` won't work on command prompt. Try running it on powershell as
`cp '.\object detection\packages\tf2\setup.py' .`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Jitesh. I run the command using apostrophes and using "copy" instead of "cp" (it seemed to work in that way), like ---> copy './object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py' .  <---  But I got an error "The system cannot find the file specified.", although the file exists.

Comment: Are you able to get the command that I posted to work in windows power shell?

Comment: Actually it worked without using "copy" command. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
copy object_detection\\packages\\tf2\\setup.py .
```

With double back slashes. This works for me in -cmd editor

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue but I went through these answers and figured it out thank you  and I used PowerShell with minor change is the path define

```
cp object detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
```

it should be object_detection like below

```
copy '.\object_detection\packages\tf2\setup.py' .
```

[image]

check this [website](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#downloading-the-tensorflow-model-garden) for more details

Answer (score 0):

`copy "object detection\packages\tf2\setup.py" .`
Try this command

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had kind of same issues. For me that helped.

1. PS D:\models\research> cp '.\object_detection\packages\tf2\setup.py' .
2. PS D:\models\research> python -m pip install .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTVn2.png)